# How to schedule a batch process in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to run a weekly batch process in an asp.net page. How can that be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any known drawbacks with the
> solution?

[Here is the blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/) in which Jeff Atwood discusses this approach. As with most of Jeff's post, the meat is in the comments where the pros and cons have been discussed in extreme detail by a large number of opinionated folks, so that is an ideal place to have that particular part of your question answered.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [Cache](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Develop a Windows Service and schedule it to run weekly once.